# How to swap order of extensions of matching files?

Tags: find, osx, rename

I am merging two folders with the following command:

```
rsync -a --checksum --backup --suffix=.merge-bkup src/ dst/
```

The idea is that if a file exists in both folders, both versions are preserved.

However, I am doing this on an operating system with a UI that uses extensions to associate files with applications. So while it may technically preserve both "My File.txt" and "My File.txt.merge-bkup" the latter file will not be useful to many users since it can no longer be opened automatically in the right application.

Can I use `find` to somehow take every file named "My File.txt.merge-bkup" and rename it to "My File (Backup).txt"? Even better would be to end up with "My File (Backup N).txt" if "My File (Backup).txt" already exists but I suspect that might be a stretch.

Comment: Is "My File.txt" an example of *a* file, or should the answer address specifically that one filename?

Comment: What Operating System is this? (that affects the tools available)

Comment: This is macOS. "My File.txt" is simply an example, I already know how to `mv My\ File.txt.bkup My\ File\ Backup.txt` ;-)

Comment: Just trying to get the Question's wording right, so that answers solve the right problem!

Comment: You might also be interested in using the `--backup-dir` option of rsync to ask it to preserve the original file names, but move them to a different directory.